# display each element of an arraylist to setText

Tags: android, list, android-intent, arraylist

I want to display each of the element or value of arraylist to tv.setText.

The values of the arraylist are from the 1stactivity(1st screen) and I want to pass it to the tv.setText of the 2nd activity(2nd screen).

Here's the code of 1st activity

```
List<String> class_code = new ArrayList<String>();
class_code.add("test");
class_code.add("test2");
Intent intent = new Intent(1stscreen.this,2nd_screen.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("code", (ArrayList<String>) class_code);
```

Here's the code of 2nd activity

```
tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("code"));
```

But it shows all the value of arraylist (test and test2) I only want to get the first value of the arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

To display only one item from an ArrayList in a TextView, you need to pass *only* the first item:

```
List<String> list = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("code");
tv.setText(list.get(0));
```

If you only plan to use this *one* String in the next Activity don't pass the entire ArrayList, only pass the String you want to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(1stscreen.this, 2nd_screen.class);
intent.putString("code", class_code.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only one value use something like this class_code.get(0)

```
intent.putString("code", class_code.get(0));
```

and you can get it from the next activity using

```
getintent().getExtras().getString("code");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the first value, then only pass the first value. Instead of

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("code", (ArrayList<String>) class_code);
```

try putting

```
intent.putStringExtra("code", class_code.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
List<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("code");
tv.setText(list.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to forward the value from the 1st screen to the third screen so I solved it using

1st screen

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("class_code", (ArrayList<String>) class_code);
```

2nd screen

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("class_code", getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("class_code"));
```

3rd screen

```
tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("class_code").get(0));
```